# Is there any recommended windows web hosting?

Tags: windows, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

My plan is to deploy a web site based on Asp.net + MS SQL server. I am not familiar with the windows web hosting market. Can anyone provide some suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

go through http://www.sectorlink.com/

or http://www.godaddy.com/

I 'm using them .. there service is excellent.

Comment: You happy with Godaddy? Many say the servers are overloaded and support is slow. Different experience? I was considering their VPS but a bit worried.

Answer (score 1):

hostrivers.com is very good WINDOWS and PHP hosting provider with reasonable price with hot deals time to time

I am already using.......

Comment: Also 24hr good features and support with chat and phone

Comment: Thanks, but a little bit expensive.

Comment: This is 18$ / year for Windows hosting.

Comment: oops, i saw the 499$/year one. I'll check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [VPS.net](http://vps.net), and get your own dedicated server. You can get started as low as $1/day or $20/month. No contracts or minimum time, cancel anytime you want - And you are billed by the minute.

Another nice thing with [VPS.net](http://vps.net), is that you can scale your server if you want to. Just add more nodes (additional costs), and instantly get more processing power, ram, disk space and bandwidth.

Have a look at it, http://www.vps.net/product/cloud-servers.

They also have Windows images. And if it don't work for you just stop using, and pay for the time used.

I'm not affiliated with [VPS.net](http://vps.net) in any way, haven't tried them, but would sure give them a go if my self-managed server at work breaks down.

I have tried [(mt) MediaTemple](http://mediatemple.net), their (dv) product. And was somewhat happy with them, but the response time from USA to Denmark was a deal-breaker.